# How do I toggle back on a function I turned off

Tags: jquery

When I click on `article.hope` I want my `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions I previously gave them to turn off. This I got it working, though I am unable to turn this function back on once I click on one of the `article.hope` siblings.

Here's what I have so far.

```
$("article.hope").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('div').fadeIn(0);
        $(this).children('aside').fadeOut(0);   
        });

        $("article.hope").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).children('div').fadeOut(0);
            $(this).children('aside').fadeIn(0);

        });

$("article.rama").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('div').fadeIn(0);
        $(this).children('aside').fadeOut(0);   
        });

        $("article.rama").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).children('div').fadeOut(0);
            $(this).children('aside').fadeIn(0);

        });





$("article.hope").click(function(){
        $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(this).siblings('article').on('mouseenter mouseleave')
        $('section.hope').slideDown(0500, 'swing')
        $('section.hope').siblings('section').fadeOut(0)
        $(this).siblings('article').fadeIn(0);
        });

$("article.rama").click(function(){
        $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(this).siblings('article').on('mouseenter mouseleave')
        $('section.rama').slideDown(0500, 'swing')
        $('section.rama').siblings('section').fadeOut(0)
        $(this).siblings('article').fadeIn(0);
        });
```

So `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` turn off just fine when I click `article.hope`, but I cannot seem to turn them back on.

Edit: .removeclass/.addclass

HTML

```
<article class="hope">
   <aside><!--background-image--></aside>
        <div>
            <h2>projet personnel</h2>

            <p>First contact</p>
        </div>
  </article>
```

CSS

```
article {
    width:100%;
    height:210px;
    /*background-color:#f7383e;*/
    color:#f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;


}

article div {
    /*max-width:980px;*/
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    display:none;


}


article div h2 {
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-size:130%;
    font-family:'ostrich_sansmedium', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;


}

article p {
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:5px;
    display:inline-block; 
    font-family:'nevis',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:150%;
    border-top:2px solid #f0f0f0;

}



    article.hope aside {
        height:210px;
        background-image:url(../images/hope.jpg);
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;

    }
```

JQUERY

```
$("article.hope").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('div').fadeIn(0);
        $(this).children('aside').fadeOut(0);   
        });

        $("article.hope").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).children('div').fadeOut(0);
            $(this).children('aside').fadeIn(0);

        });

$("article.hope").click(function(){
        $(this).removeclass("hope");
        $(this).siblings('article').addclass("hope");

        $('section.hope').slideDown(0500, 'swing')
        $('section.hope').siblings('section').fadeOut(0)
        $(this).siblings('article').fadeIn(0);
        });
```

I am pretty sure I would need to had a new class somewhere for it to work, but I am not sure where...

Comment: That is because you're attaching the event handlers with `.on()`, but have not specified the function.

Comment: Once you've detached the event, you must explicitly rebind it, it doesn't just remember how it used to be. It would be like using an eraser and removing it. It's `unbound`. So what you need to do is make it a function, such as `function do_mouseenter($ele)`, and then you call it like `do_mouseenter($(this));`.

Comment: An easier approach to this is just to add/remove a class to the element in question. So when you mouseover, check if the class exist and do whatever is needed. You can avoid unbinding/rebinding altogether

Comment: @Huangism I tried that and could get it to work for some reason. I think it's because my `mouseenter mouseleave` share the same class as my `click`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for the fast respond! This make a lot of sense, but could you give me an example using my code? I am kind of new to this.

Comment: @user3453234 you mean you couldn't get it to work? If you post the code you tried by adding classes, we can correct it for you

Comment: @Huangism Edited my post with my try with the addclass/removeclass. Added my HTML, CSS and JQUERY just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your script following your logic. The changes I have made are:

1. Declare `enter()` and `leave()` functions first, and then bind them to anonymous functions called when the hover event is triggered
2. Chained the methods, so you don't have to make jQuery search for the elements over and over again, when identical selectors are used over multiple lines

And here it is:

```
// Declare functions onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave
var enter = function($ele) {
    $ele
    .children('div')
        .fadeIn(0)
        .end()
    .children('aside')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .end(); // Optional but I use it for consistency
},  leave = function($ele) {
    $ele
    .children('div')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .end()
    .children('aside')
        .fadeIn(0)
        .end(); // Optional but I use it for consistency
};

// Bind functions to correct event handlers
// We can concatenate mouseenter and mouseleave with hover
$('article.hope, article.rama').hover(function() {
    enter($(this));
}, function() {
    leave($(this));
}).click(function() {
    // Turn off mouse events when clicked
    // Turn on mouse events for siblings
    $(this)
    .off('mouseenter mouseleave')
    .siblings('article')
        .fadeIn(0)
        .hover(function() {
            enter($(this));
        }, function() {
            leave($(this));
        });

    // Now perform stuff for <section>
    $('section.'+$(this).attr('class'))
    .slideDown(500, 'swing')
    .siblings('section')
        .fadeOut(0);

});
```

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't seems to do the trick either... `article.hope` background-image doesn't reappear back after I clicked on `article.rama`...

Comment: Hold on. It does work, but it doesn't do exactly what I want it to do. I need to hover article.hope once after clicking article.rama for the background-image to reappear and mouseenter/mouseleave to work again. Would there be a way to make it so I just need to click on article.rama for it to work properly? No need to hover it again.